# Select and modify last characters before they're clipped by overflow: hidden

Tags: jquery, css, overflow

I'm trying to create a fadeout effect such that the last 5 or 6 characters in a title bar get progressively more transparent as they approach the edge of their container.

I can't base this on character count as the page is responsive and could be any width. I also can't just overlay a gradient on top of it because there's already a gradient on the background which would make this obvious, unless I can gradient my CSS from transparent to a color, which I don't believe is possible.

My hope is that I can somehow select the characters closest to the cutoff point (before they become hidden by overflow:hidden on the parent element), like so:

[image]

I've tried to do this via the ":last" selector, but can only target tags:

```
$('#scalable:visible:last').css('opacity','.5');
```

Here's my first stab at it in a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adamnelson/PgerN/

Fix was pure css:

```
#scalable {
    background: #408800; /* Old browsers */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#408800), to(#316600));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#408800 0%, #316600 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#408800 0%, #316600 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#408800 0%, #316600 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#408800 0%, #316600 100%); /* FF3.6+ */ /* Chrome,Safari4+ */ /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */ /* Opera 11.10+ */ /* IE10+ */ /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#408800', endColorstr='#316600',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
}

#scalable:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 140px;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(49,102,0,0) 0%, rgba(49,102,0,0.56) 51%, rgba(49,102,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(49,102,0,0)), color-stop(51%,rgba(49,102,0,0.56)), color-stop(100%,rgba(49,102,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(49,102,0,0) 0%,rgba(49,102,0,0.56) 51%,rgba(49,102,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(49,102,0,0) 0%,rgba(49,102,0,0.56) 51%,rgba(49,102,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(49,102,0,0) 0%,rgba(49,102,0,0.56) 51%,rgba(49,102,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(49,102,0,0) 0%,rgba(49,102,0,0.56) 51%,rgba(49,102,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00408800', endColorstr='#408800',GradientType=1 );
}
```

Documented in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PgerN/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you mind using a pure CSS solution here?

I've used CSS horizontal gradient with opacity, and also I've used `:after` selector so that you don't have to add another element in your current syntax, this is real handy when you don't have access to the HTML or you cannot change it for some reason.. but also I would like to tell you that `:after` doesn't support IE8, in this case you need to nest an element inside your `#scalable`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PgerN/1/)

```
#scalable {
    background-color: #408800;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    height: 65px;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    padding: 0 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
}

#scalable:after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(64,136,0,0) 0%, rgba(64,136,0,0) 74%, rgba(64,136,0,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(64,136,0,0)), color-stop(74%,rgba(64,136,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(64,136,0,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(64,136,0,0) 0%,rgba(64,136,0,0) 74%,rgba(64,136,0,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(64,136,0,0) 0%,rgba(64,136,0,0) 74%,rgba(64,136,0,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(64,136,0,0) 0%,rgba(64,136,0,0) 74%,rgba(64,136,0,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(64,136,0,0) 0%,rgba(64,136,0,0) 74%,rgba(64,136,0,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00408800', endColorstr='#408800',GradientType=1 );
}
```

You can just adjust the gradient according to your needs, if you see [**this example**](http://jsfiddle.net/PgerN/2/), I've stretched it much more than my previous one.

And yes, gradient codes do look scary, but you've got a [**handy tool here**](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for creating gradiesnts which will handle them quiet well.

Note: By using this, it will disable the text selection as you are overlaying an element on the text, so in order to prevent in convenience to your users you can make something like

```
#scalable:hover:after {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Demo 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/PgerN/3/) (Hover to select the text)

Comment: IE8 does somewhat support :after, however I believe it does not support filters in after psuedo elements, and it has some other problems with it as well.

Comment: Ah, I should have mentioned that this is a simplified example. The background of the title bar actually has a vertical css gradient on it, so doing the simple thing and putting a horizontal gradient from light to dark on the right side will be obvious at either the top or bottom, depending on what color you use for your overlay gradient. I'll update the answer to make this more clear.

Comment: This led me to question some assumptions, and it looks like I can set up a gradient from transparent-opaque. I ended up with a pure CSS answer (not concerned with IE support due to the context of this problem). I'm posting the fix in the question.

Comment: @AdamNelson Sure, I would've suggested some CSS3 techniques, but as of now, there's no much support, will end up your layout in a mess

Answer (score 0):

It's not well supported, and not exactly what you're asking, but you might be able to use CSS masks for this effect:

https://www.webkit.org/blog/181/css-masks/

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/